# Object orientated Feedback pattern

Tags: design-patterns, feedback

I am searching for a good feedback pattern - concept, perhaps the question could be asked differently, let me know please. Will try to describe it.

Basically what I am looking for is the right way of making a good feedback concept. For example `Trigger` object triggers a function from other `Target` object for which `Trigger`object has some kind of expectations (maybe more then one parameter). This triggered call can also make more function calls from different kind of objects, so they would all need some kind of access to give there response to `Trigger` object with result parameters which `Trigger` object would then compare with expected ones and react upon receiving them.

I need a good concept since it must be possible to spread the functionality over the whole system. If it matters, Source code is written in C++ Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Basically there is an `Observable` objects which maintains a set of `Observers` which are registered to that object to listen on some action. When `Observable` object make such an action, `Observers` are notified that an action was made and can react on it.

So in your case the `Trigger` would be an `Observable` object and `Target` objects would be `Observers`. `Target` objects can be registered on `Trigger` object and can react (*make feedback*) on `Trigger` action.

Comment: Not sure I can fully use this pattern. Maybe I need to form question differently (let me know). 
In this case, I wish to have only ONE `Observer` object which maintains list of `Observable` objects. `Observer` object triggers particular action (for example: testing purpose) on a particular `Observable` object. `Observable` objects only notifies `Observer` object who reacts on every notification, should be also possible to react on each notifications differently.
In this case `Observer` would also have to have list of expectations for every `Observable` object. Or am I messing things to much?

Comment: *`Observer` object triggers particular action on `Observable` object.* Sounds strange to me. `Observable` pattern intention is to have 1 `Observable` object with 1-N `Observers` which reacts on that action - does not matter who initiated that action. It could be also described as `event-listener` system or `publish-subscribe`. From your description, I don't understand why `Observer` should be notified of action if he actually initiated it (maybe you are just switching the meaining of `Observable` and `Observer`).

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I did here :) OK, so I have 1 `Observable` object, who triggers some action on a particular `Observer` object and he responds with notification to `Observable` object. He then compares notification with expected result and reacts upon it.

Comment: From my point of view. It now looks like both of your objects would be `Observable` and `Observer` but they switches they roles dpending on current situation. But now it seems to me like overhead. Why can't you just call method from your object1 on object2, take the respond, compare expected result and react upon it?

Comment: And just use simple Interface between those two for notification?

Comment: Yes, why not..? But I can only suggest, I don't know your business needs as you do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22513/discussion-between-krizajb-and-mipe34)